# Экранирование фигурных скобок в шаблоне Django

Tags: django

Можно ли в шаблоне сделать, так, чтобы `{{ varname }}` преобразовалось не в значение переменной `varname`, а осталось `{{ varname }}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого есть [специальный тег](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#verbatim)

```
{% verbatim %}
    {{ varname }}
{% endverbatim %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{% templatetag openvariable %} varname {% templatetag closevariable %}
```